# RAM bandwidth activity

Tags: compiling, monitoring, io, ram, iotop

I compile sources in `/tmp` mounted into RAM.
I'd like to know fast it is! That's show/monitor I/O activity (MB/s) for this device.

*If I want to monitor HD bandwidth I would have used tools like `iotop` but for RAM it doesn't work!*

---

**Long story short:** how can I monitor/show RAM bandwidth (I/O) activity?

Answer (score 0):

All the monitoring tools are geared towards block devices and a RAM disk is not a block device.

The simplets way to compare compiling to a RAM disk versus a HDD is to:

- `date-u`, compile on HDD, `date-u`
- copy same source to RAM disk
- `date-u`, compile on RAM disk, `date-u`

Voilà: the overall performance improvement.